# IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I develop on Unity 3D and I tried to make a Combobox with the class implemented [here](http://www.unifycommunity.com/wiki/index.php?title=PopupList)

and now in my test class, I do this:

```
public class combobox_test : MonoBehaviour {

    public GUIContent[] comboBoxList;
    private ComboBox_Class comboBoxControl = new ComboBox_Class();
    public GUISkin mySkin;

    void start(){
        comboBoxList = new GUIContent[5];
        comboBoxList[0] = new GUIContent("Thing 1");
        comboBoxList[1] = new GUIContent("Thing 2");
        comboBoxList[2] = new GUIContent("Thing 3");
        comboBoxList[3] = new GUIContent("Thing 4");
        comboBoxList[4] = new GUIContent("Thing 5");
    }


    void OnGUI(){
        GUI.skin = mySkin;
        int selectedItemIndex = comboBoxControl.GetSelectedItemIndex();

        selectedItemIndex = comboBoxControl.List(new Rect(50, 100, 100, 20),       comboBoxList[selectedItemIndex].text, comboBoxList,GUI.skin.GetStyle(""));
        //GUI.Label( new Rect(50, 70, 400, 21),"You picked " + comboBoxList[selectedItemIndex].text + "!" );
    }
}
```

and I have this error :

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
>   combobox_test.OnGUI () (at Assets/combobox_test.cs:56)

I tried some solution I found on different web sites, but nothing works.

Comment: probably selectedItemIndex has a value bigger than 4. Could you debug and tell us the value?

Comment: Probably the error is inside the `comboBoxControl.GetSelectedItemIndex();` method. You need to show that code.

Comment: debug : selectedItemsIndex value = 0 and comboboxList.Length = 0...

Answer (score 1):

An IndexOutOfRangeException is thrown when trying to access an index in an array that is greater than or equal to its length. I believe that your problem is that

```
 int selectedItemIndex = comboBoxControl.GetSelectedItemIndex();
```

gives a value greater than the capacity of `comboBoxList` (eg `>= 5`), so when you try to access `comboBoxList[selectedItemIndex]` the IndexOutOfRangeException is thrown.

Comment: I checked the value of selectedItemIndex and selectedItemIndex = 0 , and the length of the comboBoxList it's 0 even if i make  comboBoxList = new GUIContent[5]; only .. I don't understand

Comment: @DouzeBriDouzeBra Where, other than the `start` method, do you assign values to the `comboBoxList` field? Please post this code.

Comment: @DouzeBriDouzeBra some other piece of code is setting the `comboBoxList` field to be an empty array. Make this field readonly and see where the compiler error occurs.

Comment: Well i fond the error --" i'm really stupid because I write start() instead of Start() ... 

thanks for answers